# Saving output of 3 channel image after using a filter array with montage collage in Matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, montage

We want to run our filter bank on an image by convolving each filter in the bank with
the image and concatenating all the responses into a vector for each pixel. Using the imfilter command in
a loop to do this. Since color images have 3 channels, we are going to have a total of 3F filter responses per
pixel if the filter bank is of size F . N
Then output the result as a 3F channel image

```
final = [];
for i = 1: length(filterBank)
    x = imfilter(img, cell2mat(filterBank(i)));
    imshow(x);
    final(i)= [x]
end
```

where :

> filterBank is a 20X1 cell ; filterBank(i) is 5X5 double
>
> img  is a 230X307X3 uint8
>
> final is just []

this gives an error
**Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.**

Then I tried :

```
final(1:1:1) = x
```

this gives an error :
**In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the
same.**

I'm a matlab noob but basically want to save all the 3d matrices result on applying each filter to a single array  then apply a montage command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set a single element (`final(i)`) to the value of a matrix. Use cell arrays instead.

```
% pre-allocate for memory friendliness
final = cell(size(filterBank));
% Loop using ii not i, as i=sqrt(-1) by default in MATLAB
% Also using numel, as length is only the size in the largest direction
for ii = 1:numel(filterBank)
    % You say filterBank is a cell, so use {}, then shouldn't need cell2mat()
    x = imfilter(img, filterBank{ii});
    imshow(x);
    % Curly braces because we're indexing a cell now
    final{ii} = x;
end
```

Alternatively you could use a 4D matrix (3D for `x`, 1D for loop variable),

```
final = zeros([size(img), numel(filterBank)]); % pre-allocation instead of cell
for ii = 1:numel(filterBank)
    x = imfilter(img, filterBank{ii});
    imshow(x);
    % assign to ii-th layer of 3D matrix
    final(:,:,:,ii) = x;
end
```